# why can we get $\frac{\partial q_t(x,y)}{\partial t}=\Delta q_t(x,y)?$

Tags: probability, analysis, graph-theory

If for the transition density $p_n(x,y)=P^{x}(X_n=y)$ of discrete time random walk $X$ on a general garph $G$, we have
$$q_t(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}t^n}{n!}p_n(x,y), \quad t\ge0$$, why can we get
$$\frac{\partial q_t(x,y)}{\partial t}=\Delta q_t(x,y)?$$

If we differentiate both sides of $q_t$, we get
$$\frac{\partial q_t(x,y)}{\partial t}=-q_t(x,y)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}t^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}p_n(x,y).$$
Why the RHS would be $\Delta q_t(x,y)?$

Comment: Do you know that the transition probabilities satisfy the heat equation ? 
In 1-D, if $p$ is the constant transition probability to the left and to the right, then (at least formally)
$\partial_n p_n=p\Delta p_n$

Comment: @Flewer47 Can you explain more? Thanks.

Comment: Since the point $x$ does not influence the result, let me drop it.
We have
$p_{n+1}(y)=pp_n(y-1)+pp_n(y+1)+(1-2p)p_n(y)$ so that we have the discrete relation of the heat equation
$p_{n+1}(y)-p_n(y)=p\left(p_n(y+1)-2p_n(y)+p_n(y-1)\right)$
To obtain the continuous limit, replace $n+1$ by $t+\delta t$ and $y+1,y-1$ by $y+\delta y,y-\delta y$. As usual in random walks, $\delta t\sim (\delta y)^2$ so that if $\varepsilon=\delta_y$, dividing the relation by $\varepsilon^2$ wille give the continuous limit of the heat equation.

Comment: @Flewer47 But how about the general graph? My setup is the walk on the general graph.

Comment: What you wrote at the end of the question makes no sense, because $n$ is the summation variable, so you cannot pull out the coefficient, since it depends on the summation variable.

Comment: @Ian Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is actually happening here is the usual decomposition of a continuous time Markov chain into a jump chain and holding times. In this case the average holding time at each state is $1$, and the $n$th term in the summation of $q_t(x,y)$ is the probability to go from $x$ to $y$ by making exactly $n$ jumps up to time $t$. The (suitably normalized) graph Laplacian appears as a result of the fact that as $\Delta t \to 0$ the probability that more than one jump occurs in time $[t,t+\Delta t]$ goes to zero asymptotically more rapidly than $\Delta t$.

In detail, if you want to differentiate at a later time, you have

$$q_{t+h}(x,y)=\sum_z q_t(x,z) \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-h} \frac{h^n}{n!} p_n(z,y).$$

This says the probability to go from $x$ to $y$ in time $t+h$ is the sum of the probability to go from $x$ to $z$ in time $t$ weighted by the probability to go from $z$ to $y$ in time $h$.

Now you differentiate that with respect to $h$ and set $h=0$. So you get

$$\frac{\partial q_t}{\partial t}(x,y)=\left. \sum_z q_t(x,z) \left ( -q_h(z,y) + \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-h} \frac{h^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} p_n(z,y) \right ) \right |_{h=0} \\
= \sum_z q_t(x,z) \left ( -q_0(z,y) + p_1(z,y) \right ).$$

Comment: Why the second term of summation is $p_1(x,y)$ for $t=0$?

Comment: @Hermi Look at the sum you wrote: it has a factor of $t^{n-1}$ which becomes zero except when $n=1$.

Comment: But the second term can be written as $p_1q_t=\sum_z p_1(x,z)q_t(x,z)\mu(z)$ and then we can obtain the LHS=$(p_1-I)q_t=\Delta q_t$. This is my idea.

Comment: It isn't $p_1 q_t$. It's just $p_1$. You're trying to describe what happens when you allow the starting point to also be random. But in the OP the starting point is held fixed equal to $x$.

Comment: Yes, I just want to show that the gradient of $q_t$ is equal to $(p_1-I)q_t=\Delta q_t$.

Comment: @Hermi Let me now if this is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much.